# left-trunctable prime SCHEME

Tags: scheme

I am trying to define a variable in SCHEME that has 1 integer argument, and evaluates to #t if the inputted argument is a left-truncatable prime number, and false otherwise.  An example of a left-truncatable prime number is 137, since 137, 37, and 7 are all prime.  Thanks!

Comment: Start with writing a function that left-truncates a number. That is, if you give it `137`, it gives you `37`, and if you give it `37`, it gives you `7`. (This is probably the trickiest part.)

Comment: No; Thank you. I have never heard of a left truncatable prime. You might want to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) though. While you post was informative it is off topic to post non questions. I do not tell people here that I'm in a bus looking out of the window and stuff and if people started making posts about stuff they did and not programming questions they have imagine the bigger size SO hard drives need to be and that actual programming related questions would be like finding whole numbers in the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a function IS-PRIME? that checks if a number is prime, and also a LEFT-TRUNCATE function that takes 137 to 37, 37 to 7 and 7 to 0.

With these two pieces you can build your function by checking if the input is prime then left truncating it and then checking that until you hit zero.